# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setMessage is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I try to fetch data from the server and then send it to the frontend.

```
function App() {

  const {message, setMessage} = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/message`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    // .then((data => console.log(data.message)))  <---- This work just fine
    .then((data) => setMessage(data.message))
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hi there</h1>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </div>
  )
  
}

export default App;
```

I got this error on the console :
[TypeError: setMessage is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wB2C.png)

Console logging the data and rendering the 'hi there' heading was successful.
I didn't know what went wrong, could anyone help me?
Thank you.

I tried to pass the setMessage an anonymous function, but that didn't work too.

```
.then((data) => setMessage(() => data.message))
```

Comment: What is the difference between `const {message, setMessage} = useState("")` and `const [message, setMessage] = useState("")`, how do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this

```
const {message, setMessage} = useState("")
```

to this

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
```

Comment: Silly me to have a typo. Thank you @J.dev

Answer (score 0):

It's just a problem with your [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Given the fact that you need to destructure an array, you need to enclose your variable names into `[` and `]` instead of `{` and `}`, see the snippet below which illustrates the problem you faced.

```js
let foo = ['a', 'b']
const {x1, y1} = foo;
const [x2, y2] = foo;

console.log(x1, y1);
console.log(x2, y2);
```